# Atlassian FishEye + Crucible under Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, crucible, fisheye

I have an instance of Atlassian FishEye+Crucible running in a server in a standard HTTP connection. But we need this instance to be also accessed from outside, over a HTTPS connection. Proposed solution? Revese Proxy, what already works fine for other Atlassian products, such as JIRA and Confluence.

But FishEye+Crucible is being a torturer problem since it does not work from outside: the logon screen loads with no style (in a CSS way) and it doesn't login, redirecting for a mistaken URL.

I have already tried the [Atlassian proposed solution](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Integrating+with+other+web+servers), but it did not work. I also tried [something proposed in another entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/437556/fisheye-nginx-reverse-proxy), and nothing happened again.

So, I ask: do anyone have a clue to make it work?

I'm using FishEye + Crucible version 2.7.15 and Apache httpd version 2.2.

My **httpd.conf** looks like this:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_module>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    <Location /crucible>
        ProxyPass http://INTERNAL_ADDRESS:LOCAL_PORT
        ProxyPassReverse http://INTERNAL_ADDRESS:LOCAL_PORT
    </Location>

</IfModule>
```

And my **config.xml** (FishEye+Crucible configuration file):

```
<web-server>
    <http bind=":LOCAL_PORT"/>
</web-server>
```

Finally, my architecture looks like this:

> Outside World/Browser <-- HTTPS --> Apache httpd <-- HTTP --> FishEye
>   + Crucible

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked this question at [Atlassian Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com/) and [got the answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/101534/atlassian-fisheye-crucible-under-reverse-proxy) to the problem: I just needed to set the *web context* for Crucible.

For details, access the provided link for the answer.